# Can I pass a child class to a reference of a parent class?

Tags: c++

I have a class A which takes a reference of B in its constructor.

```
 class A {
   public: 
     A(B& b); 
  }
```

And I have a class SubB which is a child class of B:

```
class SubB : public B {
    //omitted...
 }
```

In my code, I create a SubB and pass it to A:

```
   SubB subB; 
   A a(subB);
```

But I get this compile Error:

error: ‘B’ is an inaccessible base of ‘SubB’

Can I pass a reference of SubB as B?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `B` the only base of of `SubB`? (i.e. did you accidentally make the `: public X,Y` mistake?)

Comment: Which compiler are you using? And are these all in the same C++ file?

Comment: The code looks fine based on information given by you. I think there is some more. Please share the complete sample code.

Comment: So, is `B` defined where `A` can see it? ... I'd expect this error if you said `private B` instead of `public B`.  Also, what line does the compiler error out on?  `class SubB...` or `A a(subB);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted code looks correct though declaration of `class B` is missing. Post more complete snippet - you problem is likely in misplacing include files and class declarations.

Comment: Thanks. This is the root cause of my problem. I resolve that now.

Comment: Missplacing or directly omitting include headers. I was facing a similar problem (filling a reference to BaseClass with a reference to ChildClass) and the error was solved by including the ChildClass header, although the error message was totally misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, passing a derived-class instance to a function that takes a base-class reference is OK.

Your example compiles for me, though, and doesn't look like it should produce that error -- an "inaccessible base class" generally refers to something that was extended via protected or private inheritance rather than public inheritance.  Could you post a more complete example?